# Javadoc for a method that is not implemented and just throws a RuntimeException

Tags: java, javadoc

I have a method defined in the superclass that I don't implement this method in my extending class:

```
@Override
public String[] getParams() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not implemented");
}
```

My doubt is what to write as Javadoc. Usually, if the method is implemented, we would just use a simple:

```
/** {@inheritDoc} */
```

But I want to explicitly comment that the method is not implemented and should not be used. What would you write here?

Maybe:

```
 /** 
 * Method not implemented
 * {@inheritDoc} */
```

Or maybe:

```
/**
 * Not implemented.
* 
* @throws UnsupportedOperationException.
*/
```

Comment: I would do it like [Scanner.remove](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#remove--) does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no universal standard, but you could imitate what the Guava developers have done with unsupported operations on immutable collections. e.g. from `com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.java`:

```
 /**
   * Guaranteed to throw an exception and leave the list unmodified.
   *
   * @throws UnsupportedOperationException always
   * @deprecated Unsupported operation.
   */
  @CanIgnoreReturnValue
  @Deprecated
  @Override
  public final E set(int index, E element) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
  }
```

I would say that `@inheritDoc` should *not* be used, because it probably describes some behaviour which your exception-throwing implementation does not
do.

(`@CanIgnoreReturnValue` is from the `ErrorProne` library -- I don't think it's particularly relevant to what we're talking about, but I left it in rather than modify the code I'm quoting)